# Styling Android Views from existing XML using an Inflator

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-inflate

How should I write my XML file, where should I put it and how should I reference them in the activity?

This is what I got:

```
myView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.???someplace???.???somename???, null);
```

What should be set instead of `someplace` and `somename` ? And if I have created this XML with 2 elements (a `TextView` and a `LinearLayout`, for example) how can I make `myView` look like the first element and `mySecondView` look like the other element in that XML?

After solving it, will `mainView.addView(myView)` make `myView` appear in the Activity with the pre-defined style?

I've been reading that it is the best solution for defining style in a separate XML file and then applying it to a View created programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
See this sample code for inflating view..

{
View headerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.icms_article_detail_header, null, false);
articleDetailDataProvider = new IcmsArticleDetailDataProvider(mContext);
txtPageIndicator=(IjoomerTextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.icmsTxtIndicator);
imgFavorite = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.icmsImageFavorite);
imgShare = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.icmsImageShare);
list.addHeaderView(headerView);
}
```